# HEIC file signature

Tags: mime, file-type

I'm looking for a comprehensive list of file signature for extensions. In particular, I have some trouble to find the file signature for the extension .HEIC (and .HEIF). Do you know where is it possible to get it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hexadecimal file viewer in any OS.

For a comprehensive list of file signatures, please check https://www.filesignatures.net/

To check yourself using Windows, open a PowerShell prompt and type the following command for your file (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-hex?view=powershell-7.1):

```
PS> format-hex c:\my.heic
```

[image]

Comment: Your method can't sure what exact range is signature, is invariant and so on.

Comment: @jeiea - Can you please rephrase your comment? It is not really clear what you mean.

Comment: I'm saying it's not clear what's the signature from the hex data. ftypheic? Can you sure all heic have that part?

Comment: fyi, https://github.com/strukturag/libheif/issues/83#issuecomment-421427091

Comment: The signature from the hex data is `ftypheic` in this case. aka the magic number `66 74 79 70 68 65 69 63`. You cannot be certain that all heic files have that part so you have scan the first 16 bytes and compare signature against known values. Some will for example have ftypheix and ftyphevm.